# how to store Unicode characters from IE to xml

Tags: php, internet-explorer, unicode

when I save Chinese (这%s资料) letters to xml from IE, I got ??????? in XML file. But it works fine with Firefox and Chrome. I have specified the UTF-8 in XML and meta tag too: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`.

```
xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); $xml->formatOutput = true; 
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false; $xml->load('test.xml'); 
$elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('key'); 
foreach($elements as $node){ 
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) { 
        $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('key')->item($id);  
        $temp = $element->getElementsByTagName($child->nodeName)->item(0); 
        $temp->nodeValue = $_GET[$child->nodeName . '_' . ($id+1) ] ; 
    } 
    break; 
} 
$xml->save("test.xml"); $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: From where are you looking at the XML file?

Comment: its inside my local server. something like www/test/text.xml

Comment: Yeah, but how are you looking at it? Using which program?

Comment: I am using this code in php
xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('test.xml');


$elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('key');

foreach($elements as $node){

    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
      $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('key')->item($id);
      $temp = $element->getElementsByTagName($child->nodeName)->item(0);
     $temp->nodeValue =  $_GET[$child->nodeName . '_' .  ($id+1) ] ;   
    }
    break;
    
}

$xml->save("test.xml");
$xml->saveXML();

Comment: It works fine in firefox, but when I use IE8, my actual characters changed to crazy string like ?????

Comment: Can you show a live example URL of your XML?

Comment: sorry I don't have any live server, I am just developing under local server.

Comment: @user1138460 - Edit the question to add your PHP code; [indent 4 spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code.